# Create a new curve from existing curve - Shapely

Tags: python, intersection, curve, shapely

I have written a Python script that parses the coordinates out of a GPX file. The coordinates are stored as a list of tuples: `(float lat, float long)`.  I used Shapely's `LineString` function to create a curve that I can work with for each GPX file.

After parsing through several GPX files, I had some intersecting curves and I wanted to calculate some information based on these intersecting curves.  To keep it simple, imagine I have 3 lines (call them `line1, line2, line3`).  In this particular scenario, `line1` intersects both `line2` and `line3` but `line2` and `line3` do not intersect.  Or more visually:

```
  |
  |
--*--- Line 2 ------
  |
  |
  |
Line 1
  |
  |
  |
--*--- Line 3 ------
  |
  |
```

What I am trying to do is create a new curve from these existing curves.  The start and end points of this curve would be the intersecting points (denoted by `*` in the visual representation), and the middles points of the curve would be the points of `line1` that fall between these intersecting points.

I have no problem getting the intersecting points using Shapely's `intersection()` method, but I have no idea how to grab the points of `line1` that fall between these intersecting points.

I thought about determining if `line1` runs east/west or north/south. Based on that result I could compare the latitude or longitude of the intersecting points against every point in the line (`line1` in this case) and once I found a point that was inside the latitude or longitude of the intersecting points then I could start a new line with those coordinates that was bounded by the intersecting points.

However, this seems like a crazy amount of work.  I feel like there has to be an easier solution.  Especially since I have a very basic knowledge of Shapely.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This  link http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/84512/get-the-vertices-on-a-linestring-either-side-of-a-point  can be usefull

Comment: Thank you for the link.  This is something I have already thought of. Unfortunately, I realized that when 2 lines intersect the intersecting coordinate isn't necessarily apart of either line.  For instance the lines [(0, 0), (1,0)] and [(0.5, 0.5), (0.5, -0.5)] have an intersecting point of (0.5, 0).  This helps explain my problem though.  In this scenario, I would need to create a line from (0.5, 0) to (1, 0).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following algorithm is for splitting a lineString in 3 segments  given two intermediary points (called startPoint and endPoint)
The code looks like python but must be treated more as a pseudo-code because I can not test.

`linestring` is the line to be splitted

```
## first  find in which pair the startPoint and endPoint exist
for i,e in enumerate(linestring,1):
    if linestring[i-1,i].contains(startPoint):
        startIdx = i-1
    if linestring[i-1,i].contains(endPoint):
        endIdx = i

# build three list
# startLine from the beginning of line until start point 
# middleLine from startPoint until endPoint
# endLine from endPoint until the last point
# transform every list to a LineString 

# start the list with coords from Line starting with beginning until startPoint
startLine = linestring.coords[:startIdx]
# append startPoint coords
startLine.append( startPoint.coords)
# transform from list to LineString
startLine = LineSting(startLine)

middleLine =  list(startPoint.coords).extend(linestring.coords[startIdx+1:endIdx-1]).extend(endPoint.coord)
# transform from list to LineString
middleLine = LineSting(middleLine)

# start list with end point coords
endLine = endPoint.coords 
# extend the list with coords from Line starting with endPoint until end
endLine.extend( linestring.coords[endIdx:])  
# transform from list to LineString
endLine = LineSting(endLine)
```

Comment: I think I understand what you're saying here.  I realized a problem though.  The intersection point doesn't always lie on an existing line.  I have come up with a solution that I will attempt tomorrow: determine the shortest distance between a coordinate on the main line (`line1` in this case) and the intersection point.  Then just use that closest coordinate as the intersection point.  If I do that for the `line1, line2` intersection and `line1, line3` intersection then I can just use the existing `line1` coordinates.

Comment: The fact that intersection point doesn't lie on an existing line is not an issue if this deviation is smaller then  the requirements.

Comment: I only have a small data set, but the distance between the intersection and the existing line can't be more than a few feet apart.  Which if we're talking about a line segment that is half a mile long wouldn't change anything.  I am going to accept your answer because your pseudocode seems pretty close to what I plan on doing.  Also, you helped break a mental block.